# Allow "auto lock" while video is being played

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer, auto-lock

No matter whether I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` or `AVPlayer` (`AVFoundation`), the iOS does not allow the device to *auto lock* (to enter *sleep mode*) while the video is playing.

I have a case where an extremely slow video is constantly being played in a loop in the background.
While this video is playing, the device never goes to sleep.

So far, the only option I have is to detect when a user did not make any actions for a while and then pause the video. After that, the device counts down the "auto lock" duration that is specified in iOS Settings.

I am looking for an alternative to `AVPlayer` that will make this possible.

Similar questions:

[How to allow iPhone auto-lock while playing a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267776/how-to-allow-iphone-auto-lock-while-playing-a-video)

[Is it possible to set AVPlayer to allow the device to go to sleep during video playback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480997/is-it-possible-to-set-avplayer-to-allow-the-device-to-go-to-sleep-during-video-p)

[How to enable iPhone auto lock during MPMoviePlayer playback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489270/how-to-enable-iphone-auto-lock-during-mpmovieplayer-playback)

I had an idea to use HTML5 video inside a `UIWebView`, but iOS does not allow autoplay on those.

Answer (score 5):

***Remember this is private API, I'm not sure if you can use it for appstore release or not.***

Tested on iOS 9.

```
AVPlayer *player = // alloc init...
if ([player respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_preventsSleepDuringVideoPlayback")]) {
    [player setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"preventsSleepDuringVideoPlayback"];
}
```

Comment: If it's private API, it's **never** ok to use in an AppStore release. You might get away with it, but you won't be able to tell when your code breaks, and Apple might suddenly reject your app.

Comment: @David Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: Anyone got this selector stuff working in Swift 4.1?

Answer (score 5):

With iOS 12 this is now possible by setting

```
let player = AVPlayer()
player.preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback = false
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/2990522-preventsdisplaysleepduringvideop#